# Как можно зайти в консоль и перейти в директорию в Makefile одной командой?

Tags: docker

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста можно ли как то прописать в Makefile одной командой заход в консоль и затем перейти в нужную директорию?

bash:
docker exec -it <имя контейнера> bash cd var/www

Comment: возможно вам подойдет `docker exec -it ... bash -c "cd var/www && ... && ..."`

Comment: почему то не заходит в консоль просто команда выводится и все https://i.imgur.com/4RXgwva.png обычно в консоль пепенаправляет сразу

Comment: 1. при чём тут программа make и программа для неё, абсолютно непонятно, потому убрал метку «makefile». 2. *просто команда выводится и все* — что вы указали, то и выполнилось. а чего именно вы ожидали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В твоём варианте - выполнить `cd var/www` внутри нового шела. После этого докер считает, что сессию можно закрывать.

Для установки текущего каталога надо использовать `--workdir`

`docker exec -it --workdir var/www <имя_контейнера> <команда>`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/